# Data disappearing from the database?

Tags: grails

I am running a grails application and I am receiving the weirdest error I've probably ever encountered. One "field" in a model got data that just disappears for no reason.

I have two Model or a Domain class in my project with the following set up:

```
class Insertion {

String title
Date insertDate

static hasMany = Dataholder

  static constraints = {
    title(unique: true)
  }
}



class Dataholder {

    String product
    int somenumber
    int somenumber2
    int somenumber3
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    List<String> somedatalist
    Insertion insertions

    static belongsTo = Insertion

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The "insertion" class is representing every time a user might input a bunch of dataholders. The dataholder represents all the data for that specific product. Important to know is that the data that disappears is contained in the Dataholder model and the **ONLY** data that disappears is the `somedatalist`.

This is the magic which is completely confusing, when I insert the data and saves it. It all goes well:

```
if (!errors) {

            dataholderValidator.each {
                it.insertion = insertion
                it.save()
            }

        def results = Dataholder.findAllByInsertion(insertion)
```

I do some validating and apply data to every Dataholder and then if everything goes well, `if(!errors)` I add the insertion to each object. After that is done I save each objec, saving the data to the database. You may think it's going wrong here but just wait and be amazed.

After saving I get all the Dataholders from the database (since I want to be sure that the data was saved before printing it out to the user) by using the insertion. This is where the strange part begin, what I get back is the correct data:

```
results.each {
                it.somedatalist.each { it2 ->
                    if(!weekdays.contains(it2))
                        weekdays.add(it2)
                }
            }
```

Populate an array with all the unique items from the datalist. Then printing it out to the view and voila:

[image: the view with correct data]

Now, we just wait for the users confirm of all the data in the view and when he or she is clicking on a confirm button the insertion title is sent with post to function which would retrieve the data and to my surprise the `somedatalist` is null.

This is the functionality that retrieves the data:

```
    def result = Insertion.findByTitle(insertionTitle)

    def results = Dataholder.findAllByInsertions(result)
```

When putting a breaking point after `results` I can for sure confirm that every `Dataholder` contains the correct the right data except that `somedatalist` which is equal to `null`.

I've tried to get the data above by using the Insertion Title instead of just using the object and it works well. I can't understand why the data is populated in the database in one second and how something can just disappear?

**Test:**

```
void testSaveDataholder() {
        Insertions insertion = new Insertion(title: 'adadad', insertDate: new Date())
        insertion.save()
        assert Insertion.all.size() == 1
        Dataholder ed = new Dataholder(product:  'abc123', somenumber:  123, somenumber2: 13, startDate: new Date(), endDate: new Date(), somedatalist: ['TI'], insertions:  insertion)
        ed.save()
        assert Dataholder.all.size() == 1
        assert Dataholder.all.first().somedatalist.size() == 1
        assert Dataholder.all.first().insertions.title == 'adadad'
        assert Insertion.findAllByTitle('adadad').size() == 1
        assert Dataholder.findAllByInsertions(Insertion.all.first()).size() == 1
    }
```

This test all returns true, I am using Grails 2.1.

**EDIT**: I am using the in-memory database with "update" as configuration. So I can't really view the data. But it should be there.

Please help me with your sage advice and better wisdom.

Comment: Since Grails 2.0 you can use the "dbconsole" to look into the database, also into the in-memory: http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/11/h2-database-console-in-grails-2/

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I didn't know as I am pretty new to Grails. Will return with answers when I've checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just has come to my mind. Persisting a collection of objects into single column breaks the 1st normal form, so it is not the correct way to do it. I have immediately googled an issue in JIRA:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-1023

The correct way is to create a new domain class with single String attibute and use standard one-to-many relation.

Comment: Damn, I was really afraid that I would be that easy.. :(

Comment: You'll get into it quite quickly! Good luck :-)

Comment: I wonder tho, how come I could save it in the first place and why does not my test fail?

Comment: And do you see really see the data in the database? Isn't it only the domain instance in the memory?